# How to apply tab titles using MVVM pattern

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm studying `MVVM` pattern and I'm trying to apply it to `TabLayout` and `ViewPager2`.

I am studying the `MVVM` pattern, but I am not familiar with it and it is difficult. Please understand.

I have a question about how to apply the `title` of the `tab` of `TabLayout` using the `MVVM` pattern.

I made a `viewmodel` class and even code for `TabLayout`, but I don't know how to apply the `MVVM` pattern correctly.

But is there no need to use the `view model (LiveData)` and `observer` to set only the `title` of the `tab`?

***TabFragment***

```
class WorkoutListTabFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentWorkoutListTabBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var adapter: WorkoutListPagerAdapter
    private val viewModel: WorkoutListTabViewModel by viewModels { WorkoutListTabViewModelFactory() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWorkoutListTabBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        adapter = WorkoutListPagerAdapter(this)
        binding.apply {
            pager.adapter = adapter
            TabLayoutMediator(tabs, pager) { tab, position ->
                tab.text = "TEST${(position+1)}" // TODO: set Tab Title
            }.attach()
        }
        viewModel.tab.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
              // TODO: I don't know...
        }
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
class WorkoutListTabViewModel : ViewModel(){
    private val _tab = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val tab get() = _tab
    private val list = listOf(
        "CHEST", "BACK", "LEG", "SHOULDER", "BICEPS", "TRICEPS", "ABS"
    )

    fun set(pos: Int) {
        _tab.value = list[pos]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to set tab titles programmatically? I think the correct way is to set the title in XML if the tabs are not dynamic. You can create TabItem and give text for all of them.

Comment: No big reason. I'm a beginner and I wrote the code referring to the `Developer Docs`. `Developer Docs` used `TabLayoutMediator` to set the `title` of the `Tab`. So I did it that way too.

Also, setting tab items one by one in `xml` makes it longer due to repetitive code in `xml`, doesn't it?